# Relationship queries in Realm Android

Tags: android, realm

I am new to Realm. I have 3 classes that extends RealmObject whose objects i save to db.

Employee

FamilyMember

and Designation

FamilyMember and Designation is in relationship with Employee like this

```
public class Employee extends RealmObject{

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int id;
    private Designation designation;
    private RealmList <FamilyMember>  familyMembers = new RealmList<>();
    .
    .
    .getter setters
    .    
    .
    .
}
```

FamilyMember looks like this

```
public class FamilyMember extends RealmObject {
    private String name;
    private String relation;
    .
    .
    .getter setters
    .    
    .
    .
}
```

Now i am able to query a Employee whose FamilyMember has "some" name but i am struggling to find a way to get the list of Employee who has more than four family members.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unfortunately not easy in the current version of the query language. There is an issue tracking it here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1598

Right now you would unfortunately have to find all families and manually filter for those with more than 4.